# Reshaping rectangular image to square

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I want to convert a rectangular image to a square image.
But, I have problems.

My trial Python code is here:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('aa.png')
pixMap = im.load()

img = Image.new( im.mode, im.size)
sqrWidth = np.ceil(np.sqrt(im.size[0]*im.size[1])

pixNew = Image.new(im.mode, (im.size[0]*im.size[1], 1))
pixSave = Image.new(im.mode, (sqrWidth, sqrWidth))

k=0
for i in range(img.size[0]):
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        pixNew[k] = pixMap[i, j]
        k=k+1

k=0
for i in range(sqrWidth):
    for j in range(sqrWidth):
        pixSave[i, j] = pixNew[k]
        k=k+1

im.close()
img.show()       
img.save("out.png") 
img.close()
```

My error is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rect2square.py", line 13, in <module>
    pixNew[k] = pixMap[i, j]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py",     line 528, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __setitem__
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I've had this problem while doing an API. None of the other solutions really answer OP's as they propose to lose the ratio or add a background. The following solution keep the center part of the image as a square.

```
def resize_image(self, image: Image, length: int) -> Image:
    """
    Resize an image to a square. Can make an image bigger to make it fit or smaller if it doesn't fit. It also crops
    part of the image.

    :param self:
    :param image: Image to resize.
    :param length: Width and height of the output image.
    :return: Return the resized image.
    """

    """
    Resizing strategy : 
     1) We resize the smallest side to the desired dimension (e.g. 1080)
     2) We crop the other side so as to make it fit with the same length as the smallest side (e.g. 1080)
    """
    if image.size[0] < image.size[1]:
        # The image is in portrait mode. Height is bigger than width.

        # This makes the width fit the LENGTH in pixels while conserving the ration.
        resized_image = image.resize((length, int(image.size[1] * (length / image.size[0]))))

        # Amount of pixel to lose in total on the height of the image.
        required_loss = (resized_image.size[1] - length)

        # Crop the height of the image so as to keep the center part.
        resized_image = resized_image.crop(
            box=(0, required_loss / 2, length, resized_image.size[1] - required_loss / 2))

        # We now have a length*length pixels image.
        return resized_image
    else:
        # This image is in landscape mode or already squared. The width is bigger than the heihgt.

        # This makes the height fit the LENGTH in pixels while conserving the ration.
        resized_image = image.resize((int(image.size[0] * (length / image.size[1])), length))

        # Amount of pixel to lose in total on the width of the image.
        required_loss = resized_image.size[0] - length

        # Crop the width of the image so as to keep 1080 pixels of the center part.
        resized_image = resized_image.crop(
            box=(required_loss / 2, 0, resized_image.size[0] - required_loss / 2, length))

        # We now have a length*length pixels image.
        return resized_image
```

Example of a resized image :

### Before

[image: Big Image, 3840*2160]

### After

Length was set to 1080.
[image: Smaller image, 1080*1080]

Comment: Explain please: where do you set desired dimension for resizing of the smallest side?

Comment: Are you refering to the `length` argument passed when calling the function ?

Comment: Got it finally: it is the INT.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **resize** image filter in PIL.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('image.png')
sqrWidth = np.ceil(np.sqrt(im.size[0]*im.size[1])).astype(int)
im_resize = im.resize((sqrWidth, sqrWidth))
im_resize.save('output.png')
```

This will squash your image into a square. Is this what you want?

## Input image

[image: input]

## Output image

[image: output]

Comment: No, That's not what I want.. My goal is not a stretching but a data sequence reshapping.  Thanks at any rate ~.

Comment: What do you mean by data sequence reshaping?

Comment: Like this: [1234, 5678] -> [123, 456, 780] ... to the  square form with zero-padding. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Python library that will help you resize your images while maintaining the aspect ratio. If the original aspect ratio is different from the aspect ratio you are converting it to, it will add a background with a color of your choice.

https://pypi.org/project/python-resize-image/

You might want to look at this function

`resize_contain(image, size, validate=True, resample=Image.LANCZOS, bg_color=(255, 255, 255, 0))`